# Can't quit a fork() when using pipe()

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork, execve

I am recreating a complete shell. For that I must simulate "|". To do this, I have to use the dup2(), fork() and pipe() functions.

The code I've had the most success with is this:

```
int exec_pipe(global *glob, char *commande)
{
    int pipefd[2];
    char **pipe_commandes = my_split(commande, '|');
    char **left = my_str_to_word_array(pipe_commandes[0]);
    char **right = my_str_to_word_array(pipe_commandes[1]);
    int pid = 0;
    int status;


    pipe(pipefd);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        glob->commande = right;
        distribe_commande(glob);
        glob->commande = NULL;
    } else {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        glob->commande = left;
        distribe_commande(glob);
        glob->commande = NULL;
    }
}
```

The function distribe_commande() leads to a formatting of the command so that it is executed with execve() in this function:

```
void exec_path_commande(char *path, global *glob)
{
    int pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(glob->fd, glob->origine);
        if (execve(path, glob->commande, glob->env) == -1)
            exit(0);
    } else
        while (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1 && !WIFEXITED(status))
            error_execve(status);

}
```

Where `char *path` is the correct formated command.

My probleme is that when I send the commande `ls | cat -e` the command work :

```
$~> ls | cat -e
^[[0$
42sh$
build$
CMakeLists.txt$
hello$
include$
Jenkinsfile$
lib$
main.c$
Makefile$
src$
```

But if I send another command to the programme the `| cat -e` effect remain even on the prompt and I don't understand why:

```
$~> ls | cat -e
^[[0$
42sh$
build$
CMakeLists.txt$
hello$
include$
Jenkinsfile$
lib$
main.c$
Makefile$
src$
^[[0;31m^[[1m$^[[0;36m^[[1m~^[[0;32m^[[1m> ^[[0;37m^[[0mls
^[[0$
42sh$
build$
CMakeLists.txt$
hello$
include$
Jenkinsfile$
lib$
main.c$
Makefile$
src$
^[[0;31m^[[1m$^[[0;36m^[[1m~^[[0;32m^[[1m> ^[[0;37m^[[0m
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You don't need to `fork` in the `exec_pipe` function, since `exec_path_commande` forks for each command.

Comment: Your waiting loop also seems wrong.

Comment: If `distribe_commande` always returns (eg, it doesn't invoke `exec*` in its parent), then it is returning in the child.  So `exec_pipe` is returning twice (in the parent *and* in the child).  This is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `dup2` in a wrong place. You also have one `fork` too many.

A *redirect* should look like this (outline/pseudocode, not real C code):

```
fd = open(...)
pid = fork()
if (pid == 0)
   dup2(fd, 1) // redirect the output, just an example
   close(fd)
   exec(...)
wait(...)
```

Note, `dup2` and `close` are after the `fork` and before the `exec`.

A *pipeline* is two (or more) redirects coordinated via a pipe, so:

```
pipe(fds)
pid1 = fork()
if (pid1 == 0)
   dup2(fds[0], 0)
   close(fds[0])
   close(fds[1])
   exec(...)

pid2 = fork()
if (pid2 == 0)
   dup2(fds[1], 1)
   close(fds[0])
   close(fds[1])
   exec(...)

wait(...)
wait(...)
```

Note also both `wait`s are after both `exec`s. If you do it the other way (exec-wait-exec-wait), commands like `yes | head` will not work.

So you need to refactor `exec_path_commande` quite a bit.

Comment: I did what you say and it work thx. But the command `ls | cat -e` work only if I don't write the first wait. Do you know why ?

Comment: @BaptisteLEROYER No idea, perhaps ask a separate question with a [mcve]?